# Changing cursor when dragging over target

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created custom WPF toolbox control. I have implemented drag and drop functionality, which is working as intended but when i move the mouse (dragging data) over the drop target, the mouse cursor is displayed like this action cant be completed although code executes and is working correctly. ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/925S5.png) you can see how the cursor looks when dragging over target). I have tried following in target `OnDragEvent`:

- `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Hand;` in that case the cursor only changes for like 1/1000 second and then changes back to the one that can be seen in the image above.
- `Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;` which also doesnt work.

Comment: Does your form/panel/control (whatever is in the background on the screenshot) specify `AllowDrop=true`?

Comment: Yeahhh, it does.

Comment: Could you share the code pieces where you handle the drag and drop mechanics? Also the parts where you tried to set the cursor manually?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kfbbnn This is how i start dragdrop operation. target element is named content(which is a custom control) and this is how i handle dragEnter event: https://prnt.sc/kfbdcr. I bind it using      control.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(OnDragEnter);

Comment: You said in another comment that you are wrapping the whole control. Does your wrapper define the `AllowDrop`-Property, too? If yes, could you show us the hierarchy of the control? Like `Form(Panel(...))`? How and when do you "reset" the cursor? Do you set it in other method calls?

Comment: I forgot to set allowdrop property to true for the wrapper. I have set it now but it is still the same. The hierarchy is: UserControl(DockPanel(Grid(StackPanel(ContentControl))))
ContentControls hosts an activeX control. Well. i havent tried "reseting"  the cursor yet, since it doesnt really change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care you need to implement some events in case of drag and drop I advice to see the following link I think it will be useful and solve your problem.

[drag amp drop in wpf explained end to end](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2007/07/12/drag-amp-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end/)

Comment: Changing cursor in GiveFeedbackEvent helped. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `DoDragDrop`?

There you could set the Effect as a third parameter:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(drg, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

Comment: I did use DoDragDrop. Also, i have set the third parameter exactly like you have said and its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:
I have two Canvas with one holding a button:

```cs
<Canvas 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Height="225" 
   Margin="270,10,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="237" 
   PreviewMouseMove="Canvas_PreviewMouseMove">
   <Button 
      Content="Button" 
      Canvas.Left="65" 
      Canvas.Top="65" 
      Width="75"/>
</Canvas>
<Canvas 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Height="225" 
   Margin="20,10,0,0"   
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="245" 
   AllowDrop="True" 
   Background="Black"
 />
```

and this in the PreviewMouseEvent:

```cs
private static readonly string ident = "test";
private void Canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  DataObject dragData = new DataObject(ident, ((Canvas)sender));
  DragDrop.DoDragDrop((Canvas)sender, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Here you get your Move effect when setting the Backcolor, if no color is set you don't get the move effekt. Maybe this is your issue.
(Same behavior for a UserControls)

Comment: I have already had this kind of problem. Events didn't trigger on whole control, that's why i had to wrap it and set wrapper background to transparent. It solved the event thing,but sadly, this isn't the solution to my new problem.